# Is this a valid implementation of an UoW (Unit of Work)? What can be improved?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

**Background**

I'm refactoring an existing DAL (not mine) to use the UnitOfWork pattern. I've broken the build completely through this, so until I finish the UoW, it's a theoretical exercise. But I'm not entirely sure I'm doing the UoW correctly, so I'm not going to implement what I have when I'm not sure it actually works.

**What I have**

I have this interface, IUnitOfWork:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void AddRepository<T>(T repository);

    void AddRepositoryRange<T>(List<object> repositories);

    T GetRepositoryByType<T>();

    void Save();
}
```

It's implemented by:

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork  : IUnitOfWork
{
    private List<object> Repositories { get; set; }
    private CliCEntities Context { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork(
        IEnvironmentInformationProvider environmentInformationProvider)
    {
        this.Context = new CliCEntities(environmentInformationProvider.ConnectionString);
    }

    public void AddRepository<T>(T repository)
    {
        if (this.Repositories == null)
            this.Repositories = new List<object>();

        this.Repositories.Add(repository);
    }

    public void AddRepositoryRange<T>(List<object> repositories)
    {
        if (this.Repositories == null)
            this.Repositories = new List<object>();

        this.Repositories.AddRange(repositories);
    }

    public T GetRepositoryByType<T>()
    {
        var instance = this.Repositories.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T));

        return (T) instance;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And the IoC would instantiate it like this:

```
var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(environmentInformationProvider);

var repositoryDependencyOne = new RepositoryDependencyOne(unitOfWork);
var repositoryDependencyTwo = new RepositoryDependencyTwo(unitOfWork);

container.RegisterInstance<IRepositoryDependencyOne>(repositoryDependencyOne);
container.RegisterInstance<IRepositoryDependencyTwo>(repositoryDependencyTwo);

unitOfWork.AddRepository(repositoryDependencyOne);
unitOfWork.AddRepository(repositoryDependencyTwo);

container.RegisterInstance<IUnitOfWork>(unitOfWork);
```

**The question**

As I said, at this point it's a theoretical exercise, I can't test if it actually works, so there's probably room for improvement, but is the basic concept sound? If not, what can be done to improve the UoW?

Thanks!

EDIT:
IoC framework I use is Unity.

Comment: Yes, for me it's invalid implementation of UoW, the valid is you don't need to create you own UoW at all, DbContext from EF itself is UoW. Please don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You can't assume an EF dependency, it is in this sample, but it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Actually, more precisely, the BL should be able to use any number of repositories without having a direct dependency on EF (or any other dataprovider).

Comment: I feel as soon as you have a dependency on Entity Framework you are bound to it.  I've wrote my own abstraction around EF (interface based) - all using IoC with Simple Injector.  It does feel long winded but hides exposing IDbSet or DbSet to the next layer.  The model layer was moved out of the EF layer to allow any DAL to be used - or at least that's the idea.  Will post later if no one answers in meantime.

Comment: Why do you maintain a list of repositories inside your UoW?

Comment: What is RepositoryDependencyOne? Is a a repository? How does it consume IUnitOfWork? How does it get a reference to the DbContext? Or doesn't it?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: The list is so the UoW can provide repositories. That way the BL can use any repository it wants, fetched by type using GetRepositoryByType. RepositoryDependencyOne is a repository yes, I have no idea what's the best way to pass the UoW to it (or if you should).

Comment: @Spikee it's not the UoW's responsibility to provide repositories. Repos should be provided to their consumers through dependency injection.

Comment: @guillaume31: So how do you tie that in with the UoW?

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't think I'm asking a bad question.

Comment: @Spikee Typically you give object O a repo and a way to spawn a new UoW. O will new up the UoW and inside the UoW scope, call the repo to add stuff to it or query from it. Then O can modify domain entities it got from the repo and when its job is done, it will call `Save()` on the UoW and close it.

Comment: @Spikee there are tons of UoW + repository usage examples in .NET out there, you should find some inspiration pretty easily.

Comment: I know, the blogs I found on the topic are heavily bloated and make a bigger deal of it than it probably is. Which is why I wanted specific answers.

Comment: @Spikee speaking of bloated, you can make your IRepository interface all the less so if you just keep `Save()` in it IMO :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of the Unit of Work pattern is a little off. I would start at the [beginning](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and go from there. I built my own ORM using Fowler's patterns. Although I would never do it again, it was an invaluable experience for learning about these patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking, what you need in a Unit of Work is just `Add()` and `Save()`.

In real life, `Add()` is taken care of by your repositories. But that doesn't mean there should be direct connections between the UoW implementation and your repos, let alone that you should expose ways to add such connections.

Instead what you typically have is both your UoW implementation and the repos pointing to the same third party change tracking mechanism internally (for instance, Entity Framework's DbContext). It can be injected via a DI container with a limited scope - in a web application, usually per request.

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
  // private reference to DbContext here

  public void Save()
  {
    //...
  }
}

public class Repository
{
  // private reference to DbContext here

  public void Add()
  {
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I think that if you go for Domain Driven Design (which I've been requested/required to do), you should need further detachment between UoW and Repository, correct?

Comment: What do you mean by further detachment ? In DDD, Repository interfaces are declared in the Domain layer but their implementations are in the Infrastructure layer (just like UoW implementation).

Comment: And the domain layer consumes data from the Infrastructure using the UoW? If so, how ...?

Comment: @Spikee No, the layer just next to the Domain uses UoW - application layer, service layer or whatever you call it, but not the domain. Domain is not aware of the application's execution state and when changes should be flushed to the database.